# Auth0, how do I verify the user on the backend?

Tags: auth0

I'm using auth0, I have a front end web-app & a backend api.
On the backend api, I want to get the current users email.

Currently, on the web-app, I have a `Access_Token` and a `Id_Token`
The Access_Token is what I need to authenticate for the api, but it does not have the user info that I need (email)

The `Id_Token` can be decrypted to get the users email

Here is the functionality that I want: 
If someone hits 
`GET /friends`
My API will only fetch the friends for the currently authenticated user

What is the best way do this?
The options I thought of so far:

1. Send both the `Access_Token` and `Id_Token` to the API, and decrypt the `Id_Token` for the user data
2. Send only the `Access_Token`, then use the `Access_Token` on the API to request a new `Id_Token` from auth0
3. On the web-app, decrypt the `Access_Token`, add the email to it, then encrypt